# Compare data in two databases in Node.js and MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have created two databases (**1-btech2014** & **2-btechre2014**) in one server in Node.js and MongoDB.

I want to compare data of **btech2014** with **btechre2014**. If they are the same, then I should be able to get data in output of btech2014. Else I should  return a message. **How to compare the two databases on same server?**

The data contains:

- name;
- id (unique for all);
- cpi.

**Here is my code:**

```js
var findData = function(db, callback) {
    var cursor = db.collection('btech2014').find();//data from our processing task
    var cursor2 = db.collection('btechre2014').find();//data form replica
    cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
     /*cursor2.each(function(err, doc2) {
    assert.equal(err, null);
    if (doc != null && doc == doc2) {
    console.log(doc);
    data[i]=doc;
   i++;
   count++;
    } else {
    callback();
    }
    })*/
    assert.equal(err, null);
    if (doc != null ) {
    console.log(doc);
    data[i]=doc;
   i++;
    } else {
    callback();
    }
    });
    /*var cursor = btech2014.find().forEach(function(doc1){
     var cursor2 = btechre2014.findOne({name: doc1.name});
  //var flag = JSON.stringify(doc1)==JSON.stringify(doc2);
  if(JSON.stringify(doc1)==JSON.stringify(doc2)){
   console.log(doc1);
  }
  else{
   console.log('system on attack!!');
  }
 });*/
 /*if(count != 5){ //total 5 entries to be checked
  console.log('there is an attack on the system!');
 }*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to convert both in md5 and compare?

I dont know how much rows you have, maybe works...

Comment: I have not converted them in md5. It might not depends on the data but the requirement is that data should be same in both dbs.